# non-numeric argument to binary operator in the legend function

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm a bit puzzled as to why I am getting the "non-numeric argument to binary operator" error in my code. The full-code is provided below where I just want to create a couple of plots along with a legend. The code works just fine and creates the plot with no issues. However, once I run the code with the legend function I get the dreaded "non-numeric argument to binary operator". Which is strange because I still get a plot with the legend but then I can't create a PDF file with the output since I am running this in R markdown.

Any clues as to what is causing the error within the legend function?

```
install.packages("faraway")
require(faraway)
mod_tumor1=glm(cbind(aflatoxin$tumor, aflatoxin$total-aflatoxin$tumor) ~ aflatoxin$dose, family=binomial)
mod_tumor2=glm(cbind(aflatoxin$tumor, aflatoxin$total-aflatoxin$tumor) ~ log(aflatoxin$dose+1), family=binomial)
mod_tumor3=glm(cbind(aflatoxin$tumor, aflatoxin$total-aflatoxin$tumor) ~ sqrt(aflatoxin$dose), family=binomial)
x=seq(min(aflatoxin$dose),max(aflatoxin$dose),length=200) 
plot(aflatoxin$dose,aflatoxin$p_hat, type="p", pch=20, main="Logistic Regression Models",
     col=1, xlab = "Dose", ylab= "Percentage of Tumors")+
lines(x,ilogit(mod_tumor1$coef[1]+mod_tumor1$coef[2]*x),lwd=1,col=4)+
lines(x,ilogit(mod_tumor2$coef[1]+mod_tumor2$coef[2]*log(x+1)),lwd=1,col=2)+
lines(x,ilogit(mod_tumor3$coef[[1]]+mod_tumor3$coef[[2]]*sqrt(x)),lwd=1,col=3)+         
legend("bottomright",c("dose","log(dose+1)","sqrt(dose)"),lwd=1,col=c(4,2,3))
```

Many thanks

Comment: Why are there `+` (plus symbols) at the ends of your plotting lines? You don't use `+` with base graphics functions like `plot()` and `lines()`. That looks more like how you would use `ggplot2` functions.

Comment: @MrFlick, wow this is rather silly of me but I completely overlooked that. That actually solved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment, all that was needed was to remove the "+" signs from the code and that solved the issue.